# fecha cambia al exportar kendoGrid a excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendoui, telerik

Tengo una tabla de kendoGrid, con un campo de fecha, que lo muestra de forma correcta en la pantalla, pero al exportarlo a excel cambia el valor restandole un dia y no se como solucionarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pueden probar el codigo en el siguiente runnable:

[Export kendo Grid](https://jsfiddle.net/atsuya007/mc6u0x8d/4/)

Comment: En mi caso exporta la fecha correcta.

Comment: En serio? en que idioma tienes el SO?

Comment: En Ingles, pero no creo que eso afecte

Comment: No entiendo, pruebo lo mismo en varios idiomas y diferentes navegadores, y exporta mal la fecha

Comment: Creo que si tiene que ver, al parecer en ingles funciona bien